# Charges for Reboot and Stop an EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

The question is:

The user just started an instance at 3 PM. Between 3 PM to 5 PM, he stopped and started the instance twice. During the same period, he has run the linux reboot command by ssh once and triggered reboot from AWS console once. For how many instance hours will AWS charge this user

The proposed answers are:

```
3
4
5
2
```

Why the correct answer is 4 and not 2 hours ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, reboots (either via SSH or the console) do not have any effect on the cost. But stop/start resets the instance hour. So, the first hour starts immediately when the instance turns on, i.e. at 3 PM. The users stops the instance and starts it (no matter when, let's say 3:30 PM) and gets charged for the second hour. At 4 PM the users gets charged for another instance hour. Then between 4 and 5 stops/starts the instance again and gets charged once more and you get four instance hours in total. Read more [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-instance-hour-billing/).

Comment: isn't billing done per second for linux instances, though?